# how to call this calling WCF method continuously

Tags: wcf

I have an ajax enabled WCF service method :

[OperationContract]
        public string Test(string name) 
        { return "testing testing." + name; }

and I am calling it with following code:

$(document).ready(function () {
            var varData = $("#NewSkill").val();
            $("#Button1").click(function () {

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TimeService.svc/Test",
                data: '{"name" : "John"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
```

I want to call this method continuously after every 5 seconds using above code . How can I do this ?

Comment: Isn't this more a question of "how do I set up a timer in javascrpt?" then "how do I call a WCF-service?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the $.ajax(); part to a Javascript function say AjaxCall(). Create a javascript variable

var isActivated = false;

$(document).ready(function () { 
   while(isActivated){
    setTimeout("AjaxCall()",3000);
   }
 }
);

$("#Button1").click(isActivated = true)

Hope this helsps...